# Would "mutual acquaintance" in Mandarin be 共同朋友 or 相識朋友?

Tags: mandarin, cantonese

Which would be the more authentic Mandarin translation for "mutual acquaintance":

1) 共同朋友
2) 相識朋友?

Is it the same for Cantonese?

Comment: 像是？(共有)＂相识＂ mistyped？

Comment: @user6065 you're right! thanks for the heads-up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Chinese denotes the concept("**mutual acquaintance**") differently. These are the idiomatic sentences in mandarin:

> 我们两个都认识他 // both of us have an acquaintance with him. Or he is a mutual acquaintance of ours.
>
> 张三和李四都和我相识 // both 张三 and 李四 have an acquaintance with me.
>
> 张三和李四都认识王五 // both 张三 and 李四 have an acquaintance with 王五.

However, when it comes to the term "**mutual friend**", you can put 共同的朋友. For example,

> 张三是我们共同的朋友 // 张三 is a mutual friend of ours.

Answer (score 2):

Chinese don't usually use the term "mutual acquaintance" (共同的相识)

The more common way to describe a mutual acquaintance would be like the example below:

> Tony is a [**mutual acquaintance**] of you and I
>
> 托尼是你跟我[**都認識的熟人**] (Mandarin) *Tony is an acquaintance of both you and I*
>
> 東尼係你同我[**都識得嘅熟人**] (Cantonese) *Tony is an acquaintance of both you and I*

Answer (score 1):

According to how *mutual acquaintance* is often [used](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/146957/how-do-you-express-having-a-mutual-acquaintance-when-you-introduce-yourself), it should mean 共同的相识。

Acquaintance is not yet a friend, a friend is 朋友，an acquaintance is 相识的人。

I am not sure how you speak in Cantonese, but they write the same.